# hook_form_alter with nested field collections to add #prefix?

Tags: forms

I'm struggling with adding $ prefix to fields within nested, multi-value field collections. I'm not sure how to build this loop. I've tried to add each field to an array then using foreach to add '#prefix' = '$'. It's not quite working. When I add additional field collections, only the last instance gets the prefix:
[image]

Any ideas?

```
$dollar_fields = array(
        &$form['field_estimated_value'], 
        &$form['field_down_payment'],
        &$form['field_amount_new'],
        &$form['field_appraisal_cost'],
        &$form['field_credit_report'],
        &$form['field_lender_s_inspection'],
        &$form['field_processing_fee'],
        &$form['field_underwriting_fee'],
        &$form['field_wire_transfer'],
        &$form['field_closing_costs'],
        &$form['field_lender_finders_fee'],
        &$form['field_property_tax_holdback'],
        &$form['field_lien_hold_back'],
        &$form['field_bonus_discount_paid_by_bor'],
        &$form['field_brokerage_fee'],
        &$form['field_evaluation_fee'],
        &$form['field_inspection_costs'],
        &$form['field_insurance_fees'],
        &$form['field_participant_tax_amount'],
        &$form['field_agent_commission'],
        &$form['field_appraisal_amount'],
        &$form['field_total_asset_dp'],
        &$form['field_total_prior_to_advance'],
        &$form['field_total_from_proceeds'],
        &$form['field_total_payments_remaining'],
        &$form['field_capped_payments'],
        &$form['field_legal_fees_disbursments'],
        &$form['field_total_closing_costs'],
        &$form['field_1st_mortgage'],
        &$form['field_2nd_mortgage'],
        &$form['field_3rd_mortgage'],
        &$form['field_assets_value'],
        &$form['field_liabilities_limit'],
        &$form['field_liabilities_balance'],
        &$form['field_liabilities_payments'],
        &$form['field_total_assets'],
        &$form['field_total_liabilities'],
        &$form['field_net_worth'],
    );

    foreach ($form['field_applicant_property']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)){
            $app_property = array(
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_property_value'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_original_value'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_annual_taxes'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_annual_taxes_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_condo_fees_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_heating_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_rental_income_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_hydro_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_management_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_repairs_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_other_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_insurance_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_interest_m'],
                &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_total_monthly_expenses'],
            );

        foreach ($form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_property_mortgage']['und'] as $delta2 => $field2) {
            if (is_numeric($delta2)){
                $mort_field = &$form['field_applicant_property']['und'][$delta]['field_property_mortgage']['und'][$delta2];
                $app_mortgage = array(
                    $mort_field['field_mortgage_balance'],
                    $mort_field['field_payments'],
                    $mort_field['field_early_discharge_penality'],
                );
            }
        }
    }
    }

    foreach ($form['field_employment']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)){

            $emp_field = &$form['field_employment']['und'][$delta];
            $app_employment = array(
                &$emp_field['field_gross_revenue'],
                &$emp_field['field_income_amount'],
                &$emp_field['field_self_declared_income'],
            );
        }
    }

    foreach ($form['field_assets']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)){

            $ass_field = &$form['field_assets']['und'][$delta];
            $app_assets = array(
                &$ass_field['field_asset_value'],
                &$ass_field['field_asset_down_payment'],
            );
        }
    }

    foreach ($form['field_mortgage']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)){

            $mort_field = &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][$delta];
            $app_new_mortgage = array(
                &$mort_field['field_annual_taxes'],
                &$mort_field['field_condo_fees_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_hydro_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_management_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_interest_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_total_monthly_expenses'],
                &$mort_field['field_insurance_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_repairs_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_other_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_purchase_price'],
                &$mort_field['field_estimated_value'],
                &$mort_field['field_appraisal_amount'],
                &$mort_field['field_recommended_value'],
                &$mort_field['field_heating_m'],
                &$mort_field['field_mortgaeg_amount_new'],
                &$mort_field['field_total_loan_amount'],
                &$mort_field['field_monthly_payment'],
                &$mort_field['field_property_tax_in_arrears'],
                &$mort_field['field_dp_total'],
                &$mort_field['field_improvement_value'],
                &$mort_field['field_property_value_new'],
                &$mort_field['field_down_payment_new'],
                &$mort_field['field_1st_mortgage'],
                &$mort_field['field_2nd_mortgage'],
                &$mort_field['field_3rd_mortgage'],
            );
        }
    }

    foreach ($form['field_liabilities']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)){

            $liability_field = &$form['field_liabilities']['und'][$delta];
            $app_liabilities = array(
                &$liability_field['field_liability_limit'],
                &$liability_field['field_liability_balance'],
                &$liability_field['field_liability_payment'],
            );
        }
    }


    foreach ($form['field_investor_s']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if (is_numeric($delta)){

            $invest_field = &$form['field_investor_s']['und'][$delta];
            $app_investors = array(
                &$invest_field['field_investment_amt'],
            );
        }
    }


    $percentage_fields = array(
    &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_ltv'],
    &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_interest_rate'],
    &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_secondary_rate'],
        &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_buy_down_rate'],
        &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_net_rate'],
        &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_variable_to_prime'],
        &$form['field_mortgage']['und'][0]['field_escalation_rate'],
   );
    $all_dollars = array_merge($dollar_fields, $app_property, $app_mortgage, $app_employment, $app_assets, $app_liabilities, $app_new_mortgage, $app_investors);

    foreach ($all_dollars as &$field) {
        //dpm($field);
        $field['und'][0]['value']['#field_prefix'] = '$';   
    }

    foreach ($percentage_fields as &$field) {

        $field['und'][0]['value']['#field_suffix'] = '%';   
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for prefix not setting is,

Firstly, you are setting the values in the `foreach` loop which is not affecting the actual `$form` array.

**Your code:**

```
foreach ($all_dollars as &$field) {
  $field['und'][0]['value']['#field_prefix'] = '$';   
}
```

**It should have been:**
`$form[field_name]` instead of `$field`.

Secondly, [field_prefix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_prefix) can be applied to the form field not to the value of the form field.

Finally, array_merge is not going to help here. You have to apply the value directly to the $form.

```
$form['field_mortgage']['#field_prefix'] = '$';
```

Comment: Thank you. For the last part, it's being applied after the value because it's a nested Field Collection, so value is actually a field. The code I have works but as you can see from the screenshot, not on all instances of the field collection.